# Want to store output in an array

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a list of servers. I want to check what all automatic services are not running. I want to store it in array and later display in grid view format.
I tried below, but it didn't work.

```bsh
foreach ($i in $list) {
    $Res = @(Get-WmiObject Win32_Service -ComputerName $i | Where-Object {
               $_.StartMode -eq 'Auto' -and $_.State -ne 'Running'
           } | Select PSComputerName, Name, DisplayName, State, StartMode)
}

$Res | Out-GridView
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning values to `$Res` inside the loop overwrites the value with every loop cycle. for a construct like that you'd need to define the variable as an array outside the loop and then append to it:

```
$Res = @()
foreach ($i in $list) {
    $Res += Get-WmiObject ...
}
```

However, this is bound to perform poorly. It's usually better to just assign the output generated in the loop to the variable:

```
$Res = foreach ($i in $list) {
    Get-WmiObject ...
}
```